# How to have a develop extension in VSCode?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an extension that I'm developing, and some time before, I had it in `.vscode/extensions` with a Git repository synced.

But in new versions of vscode, it deletes that version and downloads the stable version.

How can I work then?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this workflow is not officially supported by VSCode. It simply doesn't have a concept of "development extension installations", so you have to deal with annoyances like that. I work like that myself though and much prefer it. Btw, in my experience, local "development installations" only get deleted when the version in `package.json` is behind the latest official release.

The official recommendation is, as far as I can tell, to exlusively develop extensions through the [extension development host](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension). That doesn't really seem practical if you want to use the extension in your regular workflow for a bit so it gets some testing before publishing though. The alternative there would be to package the extension to a `.vsix` file with `vsce package` and to install that. That seems rather cumbersome to me though.

I opened a very relevant issue about all of this a while ago, but it hasn't attracted too much attention so far. I guess that means most extension developers are fine with the status quo...

[Support development extension installations (#25159)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25159)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use a mayor version in develop and it should not change the files...